# Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value on iterator

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow is satisfied that the following is safe:

```
const a: ?any = {};
if (a!=null) {
    console.log(a.toString());
}
```

… but raises an error on the following:

```
const m: Map<string, string> = new Map();
const iter = m.keys();
const iternext = iter.next();
if (iternext!=null) {
    const ignore = iternext.value(); // Flow doesn't like this
}
```

Error is:

```
call of method `value`. Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value
```

Why is that?
Tested with the latest `0.57.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error message is saying that `iternext.value` may be `undefined`.

`iter.next()` will actually never return `undefined` or `null`, so the `if` test is unnecessary. When the iterator is exhausted it will return `{value: <return value>, done: true}`. Most generators don't have a return value though, so it will be `{value: undefined, done: true}`, hence Flow saying *"Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value"*:

```js
const m = new Map([['foo', 'bar']]);
const iter = m.keys();
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.next());
```

**Calling** `iternext.value()` is certainly wrong since you have a string map. You could only call it if you had a map of functions (and the iterator is not exhausted).

You might want to take a look at the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) again.

Answer (score 0):

I was mislead by the Flow error message. Changing `value()` to `value` results in no Flow errors. Still, I am not sure I understand the error message or what Flow thought was going on. The wording does seem to suggest that the potentially undefined value is `iternext` which makes no sense.

In fairness to Flow the highlighted text does seems to indicate that the problem is not narrowly related to `iternext`:

[image]

Comment: When you do `foo.bar()`, then first the value of `foo.bar` is retrieved and then that value is called. Because `foo.bar` can be `undefined`, you are seeing this message. Simpler example: `var foo = undefined; foo();`. If `iternext` was `undefined`, the error message would be rather something like *"Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value"*. I agree that sounds strange when you first read it (I believe it's because we "see" `foo.bar()` more as `foo.(bar())` instead of `(foo.bar)()`), but it's technically correct.